# Converting decimal 100 to binary 100

Tags: perl, bit-manipulation

I want to convert decimal number to exact same binary number.
Eg. Decimal (10) to Binary (10).
Dec(10000001110000110) to binary(10000001110000110).

I am new to perl. The Lame approach I can think of is to convert dec to string and string to binary but I am sure there has to be a better way to achieve it.

I am using a function to get an array of decimal numbers.

```
@Arr= {111110000,110100010,...}
```

Note this is decimal number since when I tried to subtract 1 from it's elements I got 11110000-1=11109999.

I need it in binary format so that I can do a logical AND operation on it.

Can someone please suggest on how to achieve it.

Comment: I want to make decimal 101010 to be binary(101010) .

Comment: foreach(@strobes)
{
   my $x_num=sprintf ('%b', $strobes);

}  I am getting this error while using the above command "Global symbol "$strobes" requires explicit package name"

Comment: You don't need to do any conversion to do bitwise and operations on a number.  26 & 3 is the same as 0b11010 & 0b11 and returns 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the number 10000001110000110<sub>10</sub> to the number 10000001110000110<sub>2</sub> is rather easy.

1. Obtain the decimal representation of the number. This is as simple as stringifying the number.
2. Pass the the decimal representation of the number to a routine that converts from binary to the represented number. `oct('0b'.$_)` does this.

Solution:

```
my @bad = ( 111110000, 110100010, ... );
my @fixed = map { oct('0b'.$_) } @bad;      # 496, 418, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

```
my $num = 101010;
print interpret_as_binary($num);    # 42
```

You could go through the labor of dividing the number by 2 and so on. Or you can take advantage that [`oct`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html) will interpret a string starting with `0b` as a binary number.

```
print oct("0b". $num);
```